# How to insert data, If that data does not exist in database using coldfuison?

Tags: coldfusion

I  am working with **Coldfusion**. I am new to the language.

My requirement is to Insert data into database, only if a record not present. If it does exist in database, I want to throw error message.

Please help me how to do this .

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close as this question does not indicate any effort was made to solve the problem, and is very similar to [this closed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362652/how-to-check-entered-emaild-exist-or-not-in-database-coldfusion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cfquery name="qGetRecord" datasource="yourSorce"> 
    <!--- Your SELECT Query for finding the data--->
</cfquery> 

<cfif qGetRecord.recordCount EQ 0>
    <!--- Your INSERT Query --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- Show eroor message --->
</cfif>
```

The logic is that , first we will try to fetch the required data. [Recordcount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561471/coldfusion-conditional-recordcount) function is used to find if there is any matching records.
If matching record is not there then we can insert else show error message.

**Updated answer** with cftransaction as per the suggestion.

```
<cftransaction>
    <cftry>
        <cfquery name="qGetRecord" datasource="yourSorce"> 
            <!--- Your SELECT Query for finding the data--->
        </cfquery> 

        <cfif qGetRecord.recordCount EQ 0>
            <!--- Your INSERT Query --->
        <cfelse>
            <!--- Show eroor message --->
        </cfif>
        <cfcatch>
            <cftransaction action="rollback" />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cftransaction>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: Better wrap this in a transaction

Comment: @TimJasko I have updated my answer as per your suggestion

Comment: CF is multi-threaded, so this could still allow duplicates on a busy site.

Comment: @Leigh is there any solution to avoid duplicate on a busy site?

Comment: @Leigh can we use cflock to prevent that scenario?

Comment: @RinoRaj -  Personally, I have never been a fan of using cflock for controlling database objects. IMO that is a database's job. For general cases, see the details on atomic locking in this thread [ATOMIC UPSERT in SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005).  Ignore the UPDATE part, it is the INSERT that is relevant.  For cases where a "duplicate" can be identified by a single unique value (or combination of values), I would instead apply a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to the table and catch/handle constraint violations instead.